# XSLT for multiple elements having same name

Tags: xml, unix, xslt, xpath, xslt-2.0

Basically I am writing a xsl where I need to pass a directory name, the output should return all file name for it. See below xml structure.

```
    <folder>
    <directory name='a'>
    <directory name='b/c'>
    <file name ='x'>
    </file>
    </directory>
    <directory name ='v'>
    <file name='f'>
    </file>
    </directory>
    </directory>
    <directory name ='z'>
    <file name= 'c'>
        </file>
        </directory>
</folder>
```

For example if directory name=b/c it should return file name append its directory name b/c/x(output). It should be in generic way where based on directory name it should return assosciated filename appending its directory name. Please help me how can I write xsl for it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
    <xsl:output method="text" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/folder">
        <xsl:for-each select="directory[@name='b/c']/file">
            <xsl:value-of select="../@name"/>/<xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks it working i got different issue now. I am using linux to execute xsl    xsltproc --stringparam target 'b/c'  ***.xsl  input.xml >> sam.txt. I used above xsl where i used @name='$target' but results showing blank. I used value of select of $target it displays value b/c i am not getting where is the issue

Comment: Remove single quotes from your select statement, change this:
@name='$target'
to:
@name=$target

Comment: Tried by replacing @name=$target. Still same issue

Comment: Hey i put the normalise space of target its working now. Thank you fr ur help

Answer (score 3):

I propose this solution with a xsl:value-of of the ancestor::directory.

```
<xsl:template match="file">
    <p>
        <xsl:value-of select="ancestor::directory/@name" separator="/"/>
        <xsl:text>/</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
    </p>

</xsl:template>
```

See result of the XML structure above : http://xsltransform.net/ei5PwjK

Comment: Better still, you could even do `<xsl:value-of select="(ancestor::directory/@name, @name)" separator="/" />`

Comment: Thanks it working i got different issue now. I am using linux to execute xsl    xsltproc --stringparam target 'b/c'  ***.xsl  input.xml >> sam.txt. I used above xsl where i used @name='$target' but results showing blank. I used value of select of $target it displays value b/c i am not getting where is the issue